# How can I find the domain (fqdn) for my machine if hostname doesn't return domain info and domainname returns empty?

Tags: domain, hostname, fqdn

As per the this question's title, `hostname` doesn't return domain info and `domainname` returns empty. I want to find out the full machine and domain for the machine I'm using (Mac OS X 10.5.8). How can I go about doing this? Tks.

Answer (score 3):

```
host `hostname`
```

will have what you are looking for. To extract just the fully qualified domain name

```
host `hostname` | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\ .*/\1/'
```

Of course; this only really works if you've applied the [AlwaysAppendSearchDomains](https://github.com/michthom/AlwaysAppendSearchDomains) fix to mDNSResponder. In some cases, for example you are behind a VPN, no amount of coaxing that I've found will give you the domain name if the infrastructure has not been able to set it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't have a domain defined right now

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Dominik. I haven't got a hand in the network itself but is there anything I can do as a client to get that domain to set itself?

Comment: Did you get your IP by DHCP ?

Comment: Yeap. IP is auto-assigned via DHCP. If I do a DNS lookup using $ host `hostname` it does show me the full domain.

Comment: In that last comment it hostname should be wrapped in backticks.